# How can I set up syslog-ng to send only invalid JSON logs to a destination

Tags: syslog-ng, json

I've set up syslog-ng 3.25.1 to read log messages from a file, parse them as JSON, and forward them to an ElasticSearch cluster.

This works well when the messages are formatted correctly as JSON, but in cases when `json-parser` fails to find a valid JSON object in my log message, I'd like to wrap the non-JSON log message in a JSON object (via a `format-json` template) and send it to a different index in ElasticSearch.

I understand that `json-parser` can act as a filter to pass only valid JSON messages. Is there a way to create a filter that passes only *invalid* JSON messages?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to get it working, but I wound up using [if/else flow control](https://www.syslog-ng.com/technical-documents/doc/syslog-ng-open-source-edition/3.25/administration-guide/54#TOPIC-1349499) in my logging path, similar to the following.

```
source s_json_source {
 ...
};

destination d_valid_json {
  ... // includes template definition
};

destination d_invalid_json {
  ... // includes template definition that wraps the ${MSG} in a timestamped json object
};

parser p_json {
  json-parser();
};

log {
  source(s_json_source)
  if {
    parser(p_json);
    destination(d_valid_json);
  } else {
    destination(d_invalid_json);
  };
};
```